# PHP MYSQL update syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

So I have a rather big form that is used to update the database. I am having trouble now with this block of code that inserts data from a form. Previously it was working but I changed the form to show "open" transactions so a user knows which transaction number to close. Now I get syntax/access violations. Rtransid is the key, if anyone was wondering. Thanks for any help.

```
//If there are any errors, display the form again. Otherwise, insert the data
if(!count($errors)){
    $sql = "UPDATE repairorder SET
        date = :date, 
        tech = :tech,  
        dispatcher = :dispatcher,
        booth = :booth, 
        worktype = :worktype,  
        descript = :descript,
        comment = :comment, 
        fstop = :fstop,  
        devtemp = :devtemp,
        counter = :counter,
        numstrips = :numstrips, 
        fserial = :fserial,  
        status = :status,
        odate = :odate,
        cdate = :cdate,   
        WHERE rtransid = :rtransid";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':rtransid', $_POST['rtransid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':tech', $_POST['tech'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':dispatcher', $_POST['dispatcher'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':booth', $_POST['booth'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':worktype', $_POST['worktype'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->bindParam(':descript', $_POST['descript'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['$comment'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':fstop', $_POST['fstop'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':devtemp', $_POST['devtemp'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':counter', $_POST['counter'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':numstrips', $_POST['numstrips'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':fserial', $_POST['fserial'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $_POST['status'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':odate', $_POST['odate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':cdate', $_POST['cdate'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
//var_dump($stmt); //used for error control in dummy server
$stmt->execute(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Remove the comma `cdate = :cdate,` <=

Comment: @Fred-ii- That probably is the culprit. +1

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah but I'm not going there. Let someone with a lighter mind than I put in an answer ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd like to see the error message anyway just to be sure.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened so we know what the real error is.

Comment: @JohnConde Same here, posted that wee-bit of a tool the OP can use.

Answer (score 0):

If the error message looks like this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE rtransid = ...' at line 1`, you should update your query like so.

```
$sql = "UPDATE repairorder SET
        date = :date, 
        tech = :tech,  
        dispatcher = :dispatcher,
        booth = :booth, 
        worktype = :worktype,  
        descript = :descript,
        comment = :comment, 
        fstop = :fstop,  
        devtemp = :devtemp,
        counter = :counter,
        numstrips = :numstrips, 
        fserial = :fserial,  
        status = :status,
        odate = :odate,
        cdate = :cdate   
        WHERE rtransid = :rtransid";
```

You probably miss the comma after `:cdate`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that comma... I seriously want to put my head into the biggest bucket of sand I can find and hide. Thank you @JohnConde and @Fred-ii-! 2500 lines of code brought down by one comma. I was going to post the error message but I had a sneaking suspicion it was syntax. Processed 50,000 test records and it worked  .

Comment: Here was the exception for future reference for any other boneheads: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE